# Rewrite rule in web.config Umbraco

Tags: regex, iis, vue.js, url-rewriting, umbraco

I like to use Umbraco with Vue.js and leave all the routing to Vue so I can make SPA. My goal is to write an IIS rewrite rule in web.config for using one Umbraco template for all routes except /umbraco. So far I have this

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Startview Templating">
          <match url="^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([A-Za-z0-9:._-]*)(\/(?!umbraco)([A-Za-z0-9:_-]*))?" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}?alttemplate=test" appendQueryString="true"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
</rewrite>
```

This renders the same template (test)on every route I have so that works. But when I enter /umbraco I get a blank page. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add conditions to the rule to exclude paths, for example:

```
<conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/umbraco/" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```

In your case i would look something like (I think you can simplify the match url though):

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Startview Templating">
      <match url="^(http(s)?:\/\/)?(www\.)?([A-Za-z0-9:._-]*)(\/(?!umbraco)([A-Za-z0-9:_-]*))?" />
      <conditions>
          <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/umbraco/" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}?alttemplate=test" appendQueryString="true"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```